# How can I push keys to an unsorted array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to create an array of the keys of an ordered hash. I want them to be listed in the same order in both the array and the hash. I have this hash.

```
h = { "a" => 3, "b" => 1, "c" = 4, "d" = 2 }
```

What I want is this array.

```
arr = ["b", "d", "a", "c"]
```

I have

```
h.sort_by { |k, v| v}
h.keys
```

but that returns the keys in alphabetical order. What can I do to keep them in the order of the sorted hash?

Comment: What platform are we dealing with here?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Isn't the order of keys in the hash `["a", "b", "c", "d"]`? What gives the `["b", "d", "a", "c"]` order? Don't expect other people to read between the lines. Express it in your own words.

Comment: I think you want to say something like, "I want to create an array of the keys of a hash, ordered by the values associated with the keys".  You also need to edit your question to fix `"c" = 4, "d" = 2` in the hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`h.sort_by{|k,v| v}` will give you `[["b", 1], ["d", 2], ["a", 3], ["c", 4]]`, then use `.map` to get the key.

```
h.sort_by{|k,v| v}.map &:first
```

Answer (score 3):

```
h = { "a" => 3, "b" => 1, "c" => 4, "d" => 2 }

p h.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first) #=> ["b", "d", "a", "c"]
```

Comment: That's interesting.  I didn't realize before that when enumerating the elements of a hash, the enumerator is passing an array `[k,v]` into the block, so `{ |k,v|...` it is just the normal disambiguation for arrays.  I see `k, v = hash.first` works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this also,

```
h = { "a" => 3, "b" => 1, "c" => 4, "d" => 2 }
Hash[h.sort_by{|k,v| v}].keys
#=> ["b", "d", "a", "c"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
h.sort_by { |k,v| v}
h.keys
```

doesn't work because the [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) method doesn't sort the original array, it returns a new sorted array, where each value is a `(key, value)` pair from the original hash:

```
[["b", 1], ["d", 2], ["a", 3], ["c", 4]]
```

If you're using Ruby 2.1.1, you can then just call [`to_h`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h) on the array, which will re-map the key/value pairs back into a hash:

```
h.sort_by { |k, v| v}.to_h.keys
```

Comment: that will throw undefined method keys for array error